# Installed XP after 7. Repair bootloader

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, grub, bootloader

I've installed Windows 7 and then XP (unfortunately in this order). Off course, now I have not access to Win 7 inside bootloader. Win XP starts automatically.

I'm trying to find an easiest way to solve this problem. I saw example with repairing Windows7 bootloader by terminal commands (installation DVD). I can try it, but I'm worried about unexpected problems with terminal commands.

I thought about installation GRUB. What You think? Is it possible to install only GRUB without Linux OS? Maybe it can help me?

Comment: https://www.prime-expert.com/articles/a17/restore-windows-7-boot-after-xp-installation/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've found GUI solution which works:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmCZvrctECE

Comment: First of all, Welcome to Super User! We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but please [do not provide answers that are only a hyperlink](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). While the information may be valuable, if the source web page ever goes offline the answer is essentially useless. Quote all of the pertinent excerpts from the article within your answer, then you can still provide the hyperlink to cite your source. Please see the following article from our Help Center:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)